# Display single post basen on current date and ACF field

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, advanced-custom-fields, posts

How to display single post with data based on actual date?

I have 365 posts (dates + some custom fields) and I would like to display on the home page data that has today's date from the custom field.

So my homepage should have different data every day.

My code which is not working:

```
 <?php $today = date("Ymd");?>
<?php $loop = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => array ( 'post' ),
'posts_per_page' => 5,
'meta_key' => 'date',
'meta_compare' => '>=',
'meta_value' => $today,

) );    ?>

<?php while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

<a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'>

        <div class='oxy-post'>
  
    
  
    <h3 class='oxy-post-title' href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

    <div class='oxy-post-content'>
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    </div>
</a>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: My recommendation is to inspect `$loop->requests to see if you can spot anything obvious, and also compare it to the data in the database.

Comment: I have no idea how to do this :( I will be grateful for the code :)

Comment: `echo $loop->request`

Comment: I put it after while and nothing shows

Comment: Make sure PHP, MySQL and WordPress error reporting are turned on, first. Then, after the `echo` put a `die();` statement. This will allow you to view source (don’t just inspect) and hopefully see the relevant SQL.